# How to create a pop-up modal instead of alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I a simple if statement and trying to create a pop-up instead of alert but I am not getting it here is my code:

```
if(values == ''){
    $('body').css('cursor','auto');
    alert("Blah Blah...");      
}
```

what I am trying is

```
if(values == ''){
    $('body').css('cursor','auto');
    $('body').show('#myModal');
}
```

Comment: You probably want `$('#myModal').show()`

Comment: There's not enough information in this question to know what kind of "pop-up" you're talking about. A new window? A Bootstrap modal? A jQuery Dialog? A native HTML5 `<dialog>` element?

Comment: $('#myModal').show();

Answer (score 0):

Close, but jQuery's [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) should be called on the matched element:

```
$('#myModal').show();
```

Comment: What doesn't work? It doesn't show your modal? Make a fiddle and update your question.

Comment: DO I need to add data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"

Comment: You need an element that has an id of `myModal`. For example, `<div id="myModal"></div>`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal_sm&stacked=h     This is where I got my modal from and it does have #myModal

Comment: Yes I do 
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>

Answer (score 0):

most probably you need to change it to:

```
if(values == ''){
    $('#myModal').css('cursor','auto');
    $('#myModal').show();
}
```

Comment: @bejado you are right, I looked at the first `show()` signature in jquery document. I removed that part from my answer. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work do I need to add data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ??

Comment: @Ron are you trying a library for modal or you are creating your own? you need to provide more information and complete code

Comment: NO I used one from here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal_sm&stacked=h

Comment: @Ron, its using bootstrap, do you have bootstrap included?

Comment: Yes I do have bootstrap